# How to trace/output timestamp in Visual C++ 2010 while debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++

guys,
VC2010 provides debugging tool "trace" which enable to output not only variable values into output window, but also some built in arguments like TID TNAME, PID, etc.

I want to make trace to output time stamp also, is this possible int VS2010?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the predefined variable **$TICK**, info @ [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/5557y8b4.aspx#BKMK_Print_to_the_Output_window_with_tracepoints)

Answer (score 1):

You can output the result of an expression by using curly brackets.

If you have

```
int x;
x=10;
...
```

and you setup a trace point after x=10 witht he expression  x={x}, it will output x=10 to your output window.

Just put an expression which gives you a timestamp inside the curly brackets, like timestamp={time(0)} (depending of course which API you use to get the time ....

Comment: This doesn't work in VS2008 with GetTickCount(). Are you sure it works in VS2010?

Comment: I'm affraid I use another library for timestamps (for crossplatform needs) . Therefore, I'm not sure it works specificaly with GetTickCount() but it should. If it doesn't there's a simple workaround : assign GetTickCount() return value to a variable and display that variable : "DWORD x=GetTickCount();" then next line, set a trace point with "timestamp={x}" . I'm sure that works in VS2008 and VS2010. You have an extra, uneeded assignement, but I supposed that this is used only for debugging purposes, not for production code